# Trying to program an STM32 device with ST-LINK_CLI.exe

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

I have a project developed using STM32IDE, all is well and I want to develop a test script to program the devices in bulk, using the STLINK/V2. To do this I want to invoke ST0LINK_CLI.exe

I can connect to the device and erase it fine like this:

```
ST-LINK_CLI.exe -ME
```

When I take the .bin file from my project I can program it onto the device but the chip does not run. In addition if I add the -V option to verify, there is a problem:

```
C:\my_dir>ST-LINK_CLI.exe -P C:\Temp\my_img.bin -V
STM32 ST-LINK CLI v3.5.0.0
STM32 ST-LINK Command Line Interface

ST-LINK SN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ST-LINK Firmware version: V2J37S7
Connected via SWD.
SWD Frequency = 4000K.
Target voltage = 3.2 V
Connection mode: Normal
Reset mode: Hardware reset
Device ID: 0x413
Device flash Size: 512 Kbytes
Device family: STM32F405xx/F407xx/F415xx/F417xx
Loading file...
Flash Programming:
  File : C:\Temp\my_img.bin
  Address : 0x00000000
Memory programming...
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ 100%
Memory programming...
No OnChip verification function found. Verify after programming will be performed.
██████████████████████████████████████████████████
Reading and verifying device memory...
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ 0%
Programming error @: 0x00000188
```

What's the issue? The bin file should be a memory image, right, it does not need to be loaded at a specific address? I've searched and looked in the docs, I don't find a reason that this would not work.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, solved. The .bin file needs in fact to be loaded at address 0x08000000 then all is well. Correct command is :

```
ST-LINK_CLI.exe -P C:\Temp\my_code.bin 0x08000000 -V
```